# Can I match this "range string" with regex?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to set up a delivery zone mapping method which takes a postcode (Australian) and matches it against a set of delivery zones.

The zone definition is a text block that looks like this:

`4124-4125, 4133,4211,4270,4272,4275,4280,4285,4287,4307-4499,4510,4512,4515-4519,4522-4899`

So there are 2 types, the individual postcode, or a range of postcodes to match. I've implemented the regex to match the individual items (in java):
`String regex3 = ".*,?\\s?" +postcode +  "\\s?,?.*";`

But I'm wondering what is the best way to match the range records. For example the input `4308` should match the range definition `4307-4499`. I suspect it may be necessary to parse all the range definitions using a regex and then match the input against each of those definition. Can anyone suggest a quicker way?

Comment: Regular expressions aren't a panacea for every coding problem.  I expect to handle every range with regex is going to be ugly, and possibly a maintenance nightmare.  I would prefer checking the ranges using a simple `if` statement in Java.  Of course, you are free to extract out the postal code using a regex.

Comment: do the numbers always appear in 4 digits?

Comment: and is there at least one postal code in the text block

Comment: no there are a few exceptions where the numbers aren't 4 digits, but for the sake of the ranges, they would be. The input might be 3 though, but it should match one of the individual entries.

Comment: I think if there's no better alternative, I would extract the ranges to java and convert them to java int for comparison. But if I regex can handle it in a single expression (similar to the one posted), then I think it will be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this expression will pick up all the postal codes

```
((\\d{4})(-\\d{4})?)+
```

so it will match 4343 and 4543-9987

**Edit**

ok, how about this, see if this makes sense

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String postalCodeString = "4124-4125, 4133,4211,4270,4272,4275,4280,4285,4287,4307-4499,4510,4512,4515-4519,4522-4899";

        int userInput = Integer.parseInt("4308");

        String [] postalArray = postalCodeString .split(",");

        for (String post : postalArray )
        {

            if(h.contains("-"))
            {
                String [] range = post.trim().split("-"); 
                int low = Integer.parseInt(range[0]);
                int high = Integer.parseInt(range[1]);

                if(userInput<=high && userInput>=low)
                    System.out.println("Found in range "+h);
            }
            else
            {
                int pcode = Integer.parseInt(post.trim());

                if(userInput==pcode)
                    System.out.println("Found in postal code "+pcode);
            }
        }


    }
```

this prints out

```
Found in range 4307-4499
```

is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to work out how to make this one work. So I have the user input which is the string "4308", and then I need to check if the `zone string` contains either "4308", or a range that contains 4308, example: "4307-4499" should match. But if user inputs 4271, it shouldn't match. where would the user input string fit for this regex?

Comment: oh so you want to check if the user input falls within any valid postal codes. and if so, then which one

Comment: No worries, that's pretty much what I did, but I used your original regex to isolate out the "ranges" only for checking the values, and used a regex to test the full string match against the individual one. I thought there might be an easier way to test against the whole string at once.. never mind. thanks for the help.